# FactoryGirl used with webmock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stub, webmock

My factory has an `url` field(used to fetch youtube embedded video):

```
factory :commercial do
    url 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTTygyxuGj8'
end
```

In my tests I tried to mock the request to youtube. I added following to my `spec_helper`:

```
require 'webmock/rspec'
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    mock_request
  end
end

def mock_request
  response = {
    author_name: 'Confreaks',
    # more attributes omitted ..
  }
  WebMock.stub_request(:get, /.*youtube.*/).
    to_return(status: 200, body: response.to_json, headers: {})
end
```

Isn't registering the webmock once in rspec config enough for the stub to be available through out the test suite? Why am I having to do this to my factory:

```
factory :commercial do
  url 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTTygyxuGj8'

  after(:build) do |commercial|
    mock_request
  end
end
```

Without the `after(:build)`, I get following error:

> Failure/Error: create(:commercial, WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError:
>   Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: ...tells me
>   about unregistered request to youtube and how I should stub it...

Comment: did you ever figure this out? Seeing the same thing Now. Adding a validation on a model that hits an API endpoint. Webmock stub is not registering but it *does* work in feature specs that hit the same validation.

Comment: Following this: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-stub-external-services-in-tests#sdctbs in spec_helper I changed `before(:suite)` to `before(:each)`. It doesn't seem to affect the test run time, however I don't feel very proud of the solution.

Comment: Hmm I already had mine set to `before(:each)`. For me, the solution was to remove the API request in the AR validation. I feel good about that because I think it was the right design decision, but I would like to understand the underlying *why* for the webmock in FG issue. More info here: https://github.com/18F/dolores-landingham-bot/pull/155#discussion_r57408981

Answer (score 1):

Does fill out headers in `to_return` call help?

```
.to_return(
  ...,
  headers: { "Content-Type" => "application/json; charset=utf-8" }
)
```

fill the hash with values provided from failure output.

Comment: Sorry, juanitofatas. I had already tried that, and it doesn't make any difference.